# I'm getting a "RunTimeError: No running event loop" exception in my discord.py python script. I don't know why it's happening

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot to send a simple button, I've created a class called "MyView" which just says "You clicked me!" upon clicking. I don't have much knowledge about the 2024 updates to discord.py which mostly invalidate most tutorials. So if anyone could tell me what's happening and an easy fix, it would be much appreciated.

Also if anyone has a link to a better and more exact guide for discord.py that would be helpful.

Here's my code

```
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ui import Item
from discord import utils

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!",intents=intents.all())



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f'Synced {len(synced)} command(s)!')
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

class MyView(discord.ui.View): # Create a class called MyView that subclasses discord.ui.View
    @discord.ui.button(label="Click me!", style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, emoji="") # Create a button with the label " Click me!" with color Blurple
    async def button_callback(self, button, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_message("You clicked the button!")

view = MyView()

@client.hybrid_command(name="button")
async def button(ctx):
    await ctx.send(view=view)



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Output:

````
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\Desktop\python\main2.py", line 31, in <module>
    view = MyView()
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\Desktop\python\main2.py", line 27, in __init__
    super().__init__()
  File "C:\Users\abhyu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\view.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.__stopped: asyncio.Future[bool] = asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()
RuntimeError: no running event loop

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Comment: Hi, try to create the view inside your hybrid_command rather than in the global scope.